# select noodles from response VBA

Tags: excel, vba, soap, response

I have created macro that is sending SOAP request to webservice and that is working just fine. Now I need to get rid of most of body, by selecting just one noodle, where the response it. I have tried:

```
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
    Dim sEnvlength As Integer
    Dim responseText As String

    Set ObjHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    Dim MyString As String
        MyString = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter string", Title:="string")

    sURL = "https://example.com/"

    sEnv = sEnv & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
         sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Body>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "    <msg xmlns=""http://example.com/"">"
         sEnv = sEnv & "      <Command>" & MyString & "</Command>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "    </msg>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "  </soap:Body>"
         sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"

    sEnvlength = Len(sEnv)

    ObjHttp.Open "POST", sURL, False

    ObjHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    ObjHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", sEnvlength

    ObjHttp.send (sEnv)

    xmlDoc.LoadXML (ObjHttp.responseText)
    responseText = ObjHttp.SelectNodes("/CommandResult").Text 'here is the problem

    MsgBox responseText

    End Sub
```

The response is in format:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <CommandResult xmlns="http://example.com/">string</CommandResult>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

How can I select the string that is within  ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: *'here is the problem* isn't very helpful. **WHAT** is the problem? Do you get an error? If so, please indicate what that error message says.  Without knowing that, I would suggest perhaps trying `responseText = ObjHttp.SelectNodes("/CommandResult")(0).Text` .

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that is not helping ... the error message is: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Oh. You're using the wrong object... the `xmlDoc` is the *response*. Try `responseText = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/CommandResult")(0).Text`?

Comment: Object variable or With block variable not set .... :(

Comment: That would indicate that the query you've provided ("/CommandResult") isn't correct. Give me a moment...

Comment: I have found the solution, thanks, it has to be as ("//CommandResult"

Comment: Excellent, good job!